# recursive routes in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a table

```
Category
-------- 
Id 
Name 
ParentId (null)
```

Categories can be infinitely recursive, but will probably max out at about 3 levels, i want my urls to map to the categories.
So if the table looked like this

```
Id Name   ParentId
1 Entertainment  null
2 Sport    1
3 Football   2
```

My url would look like:
 http://Localhost/Entertainment/Sport/Football

Categories won’t change too often so it might be possible to hard code them as a last resort however I don’t really want to.

i found this answer
[Routing an hiearchical path from DB with ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315815/routing-an-hiearchical-path-from-db-with-asp-net-mvc)
is this still the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a wildcard parameter is the best way to handle this. You can combine this with a route constraint that checks the validity of the given path so URLs that aren't sets of categories can be passed on for handling by other routes.